# Selecting Departments in a Department-Tree-Structure from a Root-Department excluding special Sub-Departments-Tree (see Text)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Problem:
I really have a tough time selecting a special set of departments from a department-table that are arranged in a tree structure (parent-child-strucure).

You can play with the setup on:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18a28/3

Details:
The parent-child-relationship is modeled by a string-attribute named FullPath. The FullPath-String is an order of numbers seperated by backslashes. For example: '1' is a department that has no parent. '1\2' is a department that has department '1' as parent. '1\3\5\6' is a department that has '1\3\5' as parent-department, which itself has '1\3' as parent and so on. Every department-record has a boolean-attribute named hasFKToOrg that is either set to 1 or 0.

This is the setup:
    CREATE TABLE Department
       ([FullPath] varchar(128), [hasFKToOrg] int)
    ;

```
INSERT INTO Department
    ([FullPath], [hasFKToOrg])
VALUES
    ('1', 1),
    ('1\2', 0),
    ('1\3', 1),
    ('1\3\6',0),
    ('1\3\4', 1),
    ('1\3\4\6', 0),
    ('1\3\5', 1),
    ('1\3\5\6', 0)
;
```

What i need:
A select-statement, that delivers all childdepartments of a dedicated parent-department including the parent-department itself (which is by definition always flagged with hasFKToOrg = 1). All child-tree-branches under the that parent-department that are also flagged with hasFKToOrg = 1 have to be excluded from the resultset.

For example:

1. '1' is the parent-department. The select statement has to deliver '1' and '1/2' as departments.
2. '1\3' is the parent-department. The select statement has to deliver '1\3' and '1\3\6' as departments.
3. '1\3\4' is the parent-department. The select statement has to deliver '1\3\4' and '1\3\4\6' as departments.
4. '1\3\5' is the parent-department. The select statement has to deliver '1\3\5' and '1\3\5\6' as departments.

My solution so far:
I tried an inner join between Department. The inner join approach does not work for a number of reasons. What could i do instead?

```
DECLARE @root_path varchar(20) = '1\3'; 
GO
select d.FullPath, de.FullPath
from Department d
join Department de on (d.FullPath not like de.FullPath+'%')
where
d.FullPath like @root_path+'%'
and
(
  de.hasFKToOrg = 1
  and
  de.FullPath <> @root_path
  and
  not (d.hasFKToOrg = 1 and de.hasFKToOrg = 1 and d.FullPath <> @root_path and de.FullPath <> @root_path)
)
```

This delivers '1\3' and '1\3\4\6' and '1\3\5\6' which is false because '1\3' and '1\3\6' are the correct departments. Any suggestions what i could do instead to get the correct result-set?

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined the child to be one level below, then you can't use '%'. ou need the single wild chars.
There is a limitation that this won't automatically support /12/
Change the where clause

```
d.FullPath like @root_path+'%'
```

to

```
d.FullPath like @root_path+'\_'
```

OR you can try this

```
d.FullPath like @root_path+'%' AND  d.FullPath not like @root_path+'%\%'
```

so not to accept departments that are more than one level down.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop reinveting wheel and use **[`hiearchyId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)**:

```
CREATE TABLE #Department
    ([FullPath] hierarchyID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [hasFKToOrg] int);

INSERT INTO #Department ([FullPath], [hasFKToOrg])
VALUES ('/1/', 1), ('/1/2/', 0), ('/1/3/', 1),  ('/1/3/6/',0),
       ('/1/3/4/', 1), ('/1/3/4/6/', 0), ('/1/3/5/', 1), ('/1/3/5/6/', 0);

DECLARE @node hierarchyId = '/1/';

SELECT CAST(FullPath AS nvarchar(100)), hasFKToOrg 
FROM #Department
WHERE FullPath.IsDescendantOf(@node) = 1
  AND FullPath.GetLevel() - 1 = @node.GetLevel()
  AND hasFKToOrg = 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT CAST(FullPath AS nvarchar(100)), hasFKToOrg 
FROM #Department
WHERE FullPath = @node
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387134)**</kbd>

**[`IsDescendantOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677203.aspx)**

> Returns true if this is a descendant of parent.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Where Clause

I tested my script with all of your possible scenarios and my results matched your expected. Best part is I do it all in a simple where clause. Nothing fancy.
Performance wise, it should be decent depending on your table size. Probably better than using where clause with a bunch of '%' wildcards.

```
DECLARE @root_path VARCHAR(1000) = '1';
DECLARE @RootSlashCount INT = (LEN(@root_path) - LEN(REPLACE(@root_path,'\',''))); --number of slashes in @root_path

SELECT *
FROM department
WHERE       (hasFKToOrg = 1 AND FullPath = @root_path) --Exact match when hasFKToOrg = 1
            OR
            (       hasFKToOrg = 0 --Only when it's 0
                AND LEFT(FullPath,LEN(@root_path)) = @root_path --Match root path to all FullPaths that match 
                AND (LEN(FullPath) - LEN(REPLACE(FullPath,'\',''))) = @RootSlashCount + 1 --only return direct descendants by using the number of slashes
            )
```